# I want to find the date intervals at which the employee comes on a regular basis

Tags: sql, sql-server

Imagine a employee who works in a company whos having a contract to work  on a specific task, he comes in and goes on start and end date respectively. I want to get the interval at which the employee comes to office without any absence.

Example Data:

```
DECLARE @TimeClock TABLE (PunchID INT IDENTITY, EmployeeID INT, PunchinDate DATE)
INSERT INTO @TimeClock (EmployeeID, PunchInDate) VALUES
(1, '2020-01-01'), (1, '2020-01-02'), (1, '2020-01-03'), (1, '2020-01-04'),
(1, '2020-01-05'), (1, '2020-01-06'), (1, '2020-01-07'), (1, '2020-01-08'),
(1, '2020-01-09'), (1, '2020-01-10'), (1, '2020-01-11'), (1, '2020-01-12'),
(1, '2020-01-13'), (1, '2020-01-14'),                    (1, '2020-01-16'),
(1, '2020-01-17'), (1, '2020-01-18'), (1, '2020-01-19'), (1, '2020-01-20'),
(1, '2020-01-21'), (1, '2020-01-22'), (1, '2020-01-23'), (1, '2020-01-24'),
(1, '2020-01-25'), (1, '2020-01-26'), (1, '2020-01-27'), (1, '2020-01-28'),
(1, '2020-01-29'), (1, '2020-01-30'), (1, '2020-01-31'),
(1, '2020-02-01'), (1, '2020-02-02'), (1, '2020-02-03'), (1, '2020-02-04'),
(1, '2020-02-05'), (1, '2020-02-06'), (1, '2020-02-07'), (1, '2020-02-08'),
(1, '2020-02-09'), (1, '2020-02-10'),                    (1, '2020-02-12'),
(1, '2020-02-13'), (1, '2020-02-14'), (1, '2020-02-15'), (1, '2020-02-16');
```

--the output shall look like this '2020-01-01 to 2020-02-10' as this is the interval at which the employee comes without any leave

```
SELECT 1 AS ID, FORMAT( getdate(), '2020-01-01') as START_DATE, FORMAT( getdate(), '2020-01-10') as END_DATE union all
SELECT 1 AS ID, FORMAT( getdate(), '2020-01-11') as START_DATE, FORMAT( getdate(), '2020-01-15') as END_DATE union all
SELECT 1 AS ID, FORMAT( getdate(), '2020-01-21') as START_DATE, FORMAT( getdate(), '2020-01-31') as END_DATE union all
SELECT 1 AS ID, FORMAT( getdate(), '2020-02-01') as START_DATE, FORMAT( getdate(), '2020-02-10') as END_DATE
```

--the output shall look like this '2020-01-01 to 2020-01-15' and '2020 01-21 to 2020-02-10'as these are the intervals at which the employee comes without any leave

Comment: Just an aside... format() returns a string.   So FORMAT( getdate(), '2020-01-01') would be the same as just '2020-01-01'

Comment: It seems you are looking for a Gaps-and-Islands Solution ... There are many examples to be searched

Answer (score 0):

Using the example data provided we can query the table like this:

```
;WITH iterate AS (
SELECT *, DATEADD(DAY,1,PunchinDate) AS NextDate
  FROM @TimeClock
), base AS (
SELECT *
  FROM (
SELECT *, CASE WHEN DATEADD(DAY,-1,PunchInDate) = LAG(PunchinDate,1) OVER (PARTITION BY EmployeeID ORDER BY PunchinDate) THEN PunchInDate END AS s
  FROM iterate
       ) a
 WHERE s IS NULL
), rCTE AS (
SELECT EmployeeID, PunchInDate AS StartDate, PunchInDate AS EndDate, NextDate
  FROM base
UNION ALL
SELECT a.EmployeeID, a.StartDate, r.PunchInDate, r.NextDate
  FROM rCTE a 
    INNER JOIN iterate r
      ON a.NextDate = r.PunchinDate
      AND a.EmployeeID = r.EmployeeID
)

SELECT EmployeeID, StartDate, MAX(EndDate) AS EndDate, DATEDIFF(DAY,StartDate,MAX(EndDate)) AS Streak
  FROM rCTE
 GROUP BY rCTE.EmployeeID, rCTE.StartDate
```

This is known as a recursive common table expression, and allows us to compare values between related rows. In this case we're looking for rows where they follow a streak, and we want o re-start that streak anytime we encounter a break. We're using a windowed function called `LAG` to look back a row to the previous value, and compare it to the one we have now. If it's not yesterday, then we start a new streak.

```
EmployeeID  StartDate   EndDate     Streak
------------------------------------------
1           2020-01-01  2020-01-15  14
1           2020-01-17  2020-02-10  24
1           2020-02-12  2020-02-16  4
```

Comment: but the question have start date and end date, and this code isnt working in ssms

Comment: The code does execute, what version of sql server are you using? The question asks for start and end date as output. If the example data is not correct, please edit it to properly demonstrate the actual data.